# Why doesn't Tkinter call the function bound to the root window?

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-10

I'm creating a desktop application using Tkinter GUI which uses Control+Alt+F1 hotkey. But unfortunately, Tkinter doesn't call the function, when I press these keys.

I've tried `root.bind("<Control-Alt-Key>", function)`, and it works. I've even tried to use `root.bind("<Control-Shift-F1>", function)` - and it works, too.

```py
try:
    # for Python 3
    from tkinter import *
except:
    # for Python 2
    from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()  # create the root window
# create bindings for root window
root.bind("<Control-Alt-F1>", lambda event: print("Ctrl+Alt+F1 pressed!"))
root.bind("<Control-Shift-F1>", lambda event: print("Ctrl+Shift+F1 pressed!"))
root.mainloop()  # start the mainloop
```

Why Tkinter doesn't react to the Control+Alt+F1 keypress?

PS. I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.7.2

Comment: For me this code works.

Comment: Works for me (Python 2.7.15, Windows 7).  Did you click in the window to bring it to the front?  It won't have keyboard focus otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @jasonharper, yes, I've brought it to the front. But, unfortunately, it doesn't works now, too(

Comment: What platform are you running on? Your OS might be intercepting this event.

Comment: @BryanOakley, thank you very much! You are right - I've tried to boot in the command-line mode and it worked! So, there is an application that intercepts that keypress event.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the bios, OS, or window manager you're running on is intercepting that event before it is sent to tkinter. A classic example is ctrl-alt-delete on windows, which cannot be trapped by ordinary programs.

If that is the case, there's nothing you can do in tkinter to work around that.